# In Flask is there a way to ignore a request for a route that doesn't exist

Tags: python, http, flask

I'm writing an app using Flask.
I have a set of routes and they work.
What I want to do on the client side is to ignore any requests to invalid URLs. That is I do not want to render any 404/error pages in the app. I would like an alert that says the URL is invalid and for the browser to simply stay on the same page.

I don't want to be checking the URLs in JavaScript on the client, as this would expose them.

I have a route which responds correctly to unknown URLs:

```
@app.errorhandler(404) 
def non_existant_route(error):
   return jsonify({"no":"such page"})
```

If I delete the return statement I get a 500 error. 
I can't use abort()

Does this idea violate some HTTP principle?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that works? It isn't valid Python.

Comment: @dirn The code snippet is a Flask route. What's not valid about it? And what difference does it make? The def has to return something or else the browser displays a 500 ERROR, which is exactly what I want a solution to

Comment: `-` is not valid in a Python identifier, in this case a function name.

Comment: @dirn you're right. I fixed the function name

Comment: Do you want this to work even coming from external pages?

Comment: Are the users logged in to the app?

Comment: @katz there are sections that need a login (these routes are the ones I don't want as variables in the browser) and a public interface which doesn't require logging in. It is this public face where I want to handle random urls by having the browser not respond with any redirect/render. Not sure what you mean by external pages?

Comment: As well as 404, Flask seems to return 405 `MethodNotAllowed` for paths which don't translate to a route, which is a sub-class of `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException`. You might find declaring an error handler for `MethodNotAllowed` may only trap bad routes, or at least sufficiently so for your purposes, and also intercept 404s: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/#application-errors

Answer (score 2):

I've decided a solution to this is too hard! I can not find any way to get the browser to ignore a response. There is no response header for 'do nothing'. If there was we would probably never see a webserver error again, which would not be good.

I could ajaxify all the requests as a way to grab the response headers and analyze them before any rendering or redirecting happens. That starts to break all the navigation (back buttons at least) and the pretty URLs. I could bung in a JS routing framework etc, and while I'm leaning how it works I'm not building my app (I already have enough to learn!)

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

If you come up with something great post it anyway, I'm not the first to ask this question, and probably not the last.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a "catch-all" endpoint. Typically, it seems a catch-all endpoint would return a generic 404, but in your case, you probably want to return a 200 with some contextual information. Here's basically how you can do it (credit goes to http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    # returns a 200 (not a 404) with the following contents:
    return 'your custom error content\n'

# This is just one of your other valid routes:
@app.route('/stuff')
def stuff():
    return 'stuff\n'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

If you run this and curl various endpoints of the test app, here's what you get:

```
$ curl localhost:5000/stuff
stuff
$ curl localhost:5000/foo/bar
your custom error content
$ curl localhost:5000/otherstuff
your custom error content
```

As you can see, your other routes will still work as you expect.

Comment: The link above is no longer valid, and also couldn't get this solution to work as described.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading about a javascript library some days ago (but I don't remember the name...). The clou with this library was, that all links and form submits were loaded not directly into the browser "_top" frame/window but into a hidden div and afterwards, when done, the content of the page was replaced by the content of this hidden div.

So if you want to catch bad links and such on client side you could hook up all links and submits and check the http response code. If it is not 200 (ok) you display an error. If it is okay you decide, if you replace the old page with the new content.

But there are two problems with this solution:
1. You would have to change the browsers location (in the address bar) without reloading the page of course!
2. It might get tricky to post some file uploads with javascript.

If I find the link or name of the js-library I saw, I will tell you!